# How can I make my height responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, height

I have a use case in which I want to keep the height of a span (or div, or whatever) responsive with regard to the screen size. Also, above this span there would be a header with a fixed height (I mean I want to keep it fixed height even when the screen height changes).

I have made a plunker to illustrate:
link : [plunker responsive height](http://plnkr.co/edit/KtLMpdvYSo6jbREnMFHP?p=preview)

In the above plunker:

1. the green span must never go out of the black border span.
2. the purple div's height must not be smaller than the height in the plunker.
3. the scroll bar must come only in the green div.
4. **the height of the green div should adjust itself when the screen size is reduced**.
5. **the header must always remain on the top**.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="border:1px solid red;height:90%">
<head>
<style>

    .black{
    border:1px solid black;
    height:70%;
    display:block;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body style="height:100%">
    <span class="black">
        <span style="display:block;border:1px solid purple;height:15%;min-height:70px;">
            Fixed Header - purple color <br>height givnen  15% <br> and min height also set
        </span>
        <span style="margin-top:2%;border :1px solid green;display: block;overflow:scroll;height:75%">
        <ul>
            <li>Responsive body</li>
            <br>
            <li>Should never go out of the black boder span</li>
            <br>
            <li>should be responsive acccording to the height of the body</li>
            <br>
            <li>Item4</li>
            <br>
            <li>Item5</li>
            <br>
            <li>Item6</li>
            <li>Item7</li>
            <br>
            <li>Item8</li><li>Item1</li>
            <li>Item9</li>
            <li>Item10</li>
            <li>Item11</li>
            <li>Item7</li>
            <br>
            <li>Item8</li><li>Item1</li>
            <li>Item9</li>
            <li>Item10</li>
            <li>Item11</li>
        </ul>
        </span>
    </span>
</body>
</html>
```

Please Note: I don't want to use JavaScript for any dynamic sizing

Best Practices Help:

Is it okay to give height in percentages to the HTML and the body(like I am trying to do in the plunker) with the aim to achieve responsiveness height-wise?

Comment: I'm not fully understanding your 5th point. By "always remain on top" do you mean like on [this site](http://learnlayout.com/position.html) the yellow box stays on the bottom right?

Comment: Also, don't use `<span>` and then set it to `display:block` just use a `<div>` instead

Comment: So it's the height of a span (or div, or whatever) and not your own height as it is in the title :)

Comment: @parchment : no - i meant that the scroll would only come for the green area and not the whole body/html/outermost span.

Comment: @Paulie_D i know that :).

Comment: could anybody please help me on that

Answer (score 0):

Since the min-height is declared for header it will be ensured that the header will have height of 70px minimum independent to screen size.

I am not clear whether you mean that header should remain fixed at its position even when the other contents are scrolled? or header should move along with the content?
To ensure that header always remains on top but move when the whole you can add positioning to your css code. ie for .black class `{position:absolute;}` and for the header span `{position:relative;top:0px;left:0px;}`

But to make the header fixed at the same place you can add `position:fixed;top:0px;left:0px;` only to header span.

yes height is given in percentage to the respective classes to ensure responsiveness.